# Continuous partial functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In general topology, let $A\times B$ be a product topological space and $(x,y)$ be some point in it. Is it possible for a function defined on $A\times B$ to have continuous partial functions at $(x,y)$ (that is $f_1 : t \rightarrow f(x,t)$ and $f_2$ are continuous at $y \in B$ resp. $x\in A$) and not be continuous at $x$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by partial function? Does the function defined in $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ which is $1$ on the axes and $0$ otherwise have continuous partial functions at $0$?

Comment: Thx let me make that clearer

Comment: Well actually you've just answered my question !